# How to make a function that loops alert every specific time?

Tags: javascript

I want to make a break alerting function every time a user enter a specific time, the user will submit his 4 breaks times, and I want a function to alert him when the break time is now.

I have reached this point :

```js
function Submit() {
  var break1Hours = document.getElementById("break1Hours").value,
    break1Minutes = document.getElementById("break1Minutes").value,
    break2Hours = document.getElementById("break2Hours").value,
    break2Minutes = document.getElementById("break2Minutes").value,
    break3Hours = document.getElementById("break3Hours").value,
    break3Minutes = document.getElementById("break3Minutes").value,
    break4Hours = document.getElementById("break4Hours").value,
    break4Minutes = document.getElementById("break4Minutes").value,
    break1AmPm,
    break2AmPm,
    break3AmPm,
    break4AmPm,
    currentDate = new Date(),
    currentHours = currentDate.getHours(),
    stringHours = currentHours.toString(), // => 9
    currentMinutes = currentDate.getMinutes();

  if (break1Hours < 10) {
    break1 = "0" + break1Hours;
    break1AmPm = "AM";
  } else if (break1Hours > 12 && break1Hours < 22) {
    break1 = "0" + (break1Hours - 12);
    break1AmPm = "PM";
  } else if (break1Hours >= 22) {
    break1 = break1Hours - 12;
    break1AmPm = "PM";
  } else {
    break1 = break1Hours;
    break1AmPm = "AM";
  }


  if (break2Hours < 10) {
    break2 = "0" + break2Hours;
    break2AmPm = "AM";
  } else if (break2Hours > 12 && break2Hours < 22) {
    break2 = "0" + (break2Hours - 12);
    break2AmPm = "PM";
  } else if (break2Hours >= 22) {
    break2 = break2Hours - 12;
    break2AmPm = "PM";
  } else {
    break2 = break2Hours;
    break2AmPm = "AM";
  }

  if (break3Hours < 10) {
    break3 = "0" + break3Hours;
    break3AmPm = "AM";
  } else if (break3Hours > 12 && break3Hours < 22) {
    break3 = "0" + (break3Hours - 12);
    break3AmPm = "PM";
  } else if (break3Hours >= 22) {
    break3 = break3Hours - 12;
    break3AmPm = "PM";
  } else {
    break3 = break3Hours;
    break3AmPm = "AM";
  }

  if (break4Hours < 10) {
    break4 = "0" + break4Hours;
    break4AmPm = "AM";
  } else if (break4Hours > 12 && break4Hours < 22) {
    break4 = "0" + (break4Hours - 12);
    break4AmPm = "PM";
  } else if (break4Hours >= 22) {
    break4 = break4Hours - 12;
    break4AmPm = "PM";
  } else {
    break4 = break4Hours;
    break4AmPm = "AM";
  }

  var diff1 = ((break1Hours - currentHours) * 60) + (break1Minutes - currentMinutes),
    diff2 = ((break2Hours - currentHours) * 60) + (break2Minutes - currentMinutes),
    diff3 = ((break3Hours - currentHours) * 60) + (break3Minutes - currentMinutes),
    diff4 = ((break4Hours - currentHours) * 60) + (break4Minutes - currentMinutes),
    myVar = setTimeout(alertFunc, (diff1 * 60000));


  function alertFunc() {

    alert("your Have a break right now, Enjoy your Break and Do Not Exceed it");
    setTimeout(alertFunc2, (diff2 * 60000));

  }

  function alertFunc2() {

    alert("your Have a break right now, Enjoy your Break and Do Not Exceed it");
    setTimeout(alertFunc3, (diff3 * 60000));

  }

  function alertFunc3() {

    alert("your Have a break right now, Enjoy your Break and Do Not Exceed it");
    setTimeout(alertFunc4, (diff4 * 60000));

  }

  function alertFunc4() {

    alert("your Have a break right now, Enjoy your Break and Do Not Exceed it");
    clearTimeout(alertFunc4, 1000);

  }
}
```

the first alert pops up in the exact time perfectly but the other alerts keeps poping up right after the first alert, not in time specified by the user.

and this is the HTML input for the user , if there is a simple way to do it plz help

```html
<label for="break1">Break 1:</label>
<select id="break1Hours">
  <option value="1">01 AM</option>
  <option value="2">02 AM</option>
  <option value="3">03 AM</option>
  <option value="4">04 AM</option>
  <option value="5">05 AM</option>
  <option value="6">06 AM</option>
  <option value="7">07 AM</option>
  <option value="8">08 AM</option>
  <option value="9">09 AM</option>
  <option value="10">10 AM</option>
  <option value="11">11 AM</option>
  <option value="12">12 AM</option>
  <option value="13">01 PM</option>
  <option value="14">02 PM</option>
  <option value="15">03 PM</option>
  <option value="16">04 PM</option>
  <option value="17">05 PM</option>
  <option value="18">06 PM</option>
  <option value="19">07 PM</option>
  <option value="20">08 PM</option>
  <option value="21">09 PM</option>
  <option value="22">10 PM</option>
  <option value="23">11 PM</option>
  <option value="24">12 PM</option>
</select>

<select id="break1Minutes">
  <option value="00">00</option>
  <option value="15">15</option>
  <option value="30">30</option>
  <option value="45">45</option>
</select>
```

and so on for the other three breaks ,

Comment: `console.log(diff1, diff2, diff3, diff4);` - ?

Comment: Igor do you mean that you need to see what console.log will output ?

Comment: yes *(12 more to go...)*

Comment: the output was (84 444 624 684), my local time when i called the funtion was in order 4:37AM , and the breaks time was 6:00AM, 12:00AM , 03:00PM , 04:00PM ,

Comment: Igor , plz reply

Comment: What you are describing resembles the behaviour of `setTimeout` when `delay` parameter exceeds 32-bit integer value - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout. Although the numbers that you cite are far smaller. Suggestion: do not make a timeout with delay of several hours. Make small timeouts and recalculate remaining time when they fire.

Comment: Igor , really thanks , when i made the difference between timeouts smaller , it really worked ,, but the issue is how can i recalculate the difference of hours to be smaller ?!

Comment: I would put the timeout for 10 minutes and recalculate remaining time when the timeout fires. If the remaining time is greater than 10 minutes - repeat. If the remaining time is less than 10 minutes - put the next timeout delay equal to remaining time.

Comment: thanks igor very much that was the way i calculated it.

Comment: Glad I could help. I put my two last comments in the answer. If you choose, you can accept it by clicking the checkmark left of the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are describing resembles the behaviour of setTimeout when delay parameter exceeds 32-bit integer value - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout. Although the numbers that you cite are far smaller. Suggestion: do not make a timeout with delay of several hours. Make small timeouts and recalculate remaining time when they fire.

---

I would put the timeout for 10 minutes and recalculate remaining time when the timeout fires. If the remaining time is greater than 10 minutes - repeat. If the remaining time is less than 10 minutes - put the next timeout delay equal to remaining time.